# Converting to C++ from C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, registry

I have done pretty much all my programming using C# and very much a newbie to C++. However now I have to convert to C++ and is finding it a bit difficult. For example, I wrote a pretty simple program using C# to acquire a RegistryKey, then using a recursive function I iterate through my registry key to find a specific key and then get the values I want. No problem, I can write that program in 10 minutes using C#. Here is the code.

***My primary function. It gets Bluetooth Registry Key and then call the recursive function.***

```
private static void CheckOpenComPorts()
{
            RegistryKey blueToothPorts = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\Bluetooth");

            List<string> foundPorts = new List<string>();
            AddFoundPortsToList(blueToothPorts, ref foundPorts);

            //Rest of the program; not relevant here.            
}
```

***Recursive Function. Iterates the passed Key to find out necessary values.***

```
private static void AddFoundPortsToList(RegistryKey regKey, ref List<string> ports)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] subKeys = regKey.GetSubKeyNames();

                if (subKeys != null)
                {
                    foreach (string subKey in subKeys)
                    {
                        AddFoundPortsToList(regKey.OpenSubKey(subKey), ref ports);
                    }
                }

                if (regKey.Name.EndsWith("Device Parameters"))
                {
                    string str = System.Convert.ToString(regKey.GetValue("PortName"));
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) == false)
                    {
                        ports.Add(str);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Security.SecurityException ex)
            {
                ;
            }
        }
```

The above code works fine, but when I tried to convert it to C++, I'm pretty lost.
**Note : I'm using a Win32 Console C++ Program.**

I figured out that I can do something like the following to get the Bluetooth Registry Key.

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Enum\\Bluetooth", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey)
```

But after that, I'm pretty lost about the recursive function. Specially, how do I get the available subkeys of the passed registry key ***when I do NOT know the subkey names***?. Or in short, what is the equivalent behavior of RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames() in C++?

As I am only beginning this thing a code sample with some explanations would be great.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in c++/CLI or in win32? You said, Win32 Console, but I just want to make sure that you aren't using C++/CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to transition from .NET to native C++ programming.  (i.e. no CLI and no .NET framework, which you could still use if you enabled managed C++ compilation).

If you spent a ton of time in C# land, you are probably very used to a ton of very convenient classes for just about everything imaginable and all you have to do is hit "." and let the Intellisense list the methods.  Well.... you can forget all those conveniences :)

There is no such (at least not complete) framework in C++ so often you have to turn to Win32 API. MSDN Library is YOUR FRIEND.  If you want to get good at C++, learn how to read it and learn how to look things up (not just by name, but learn where different categories are).  In this case, if you search for the function you found, you will find a whole set of functions that work on registry.  So now, looking at other methods in the same category in MSDN library, you can find [RegEnumKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724862%28VS.85%29.aspx). (hint: make sure to switch MSDN library UI to classical view, that makes it much easier to navigate between topics.  I don't know what MS was thinking with their "new" look and feel)

As you start using Win32 API you will realize what a pain it is, especially coming from C#.  But you don't have to use it directly (or at least not every time).  You can use other libraries, for example ATL provides you with CRegKey class which makes working with registry much simpler.  If you can't find the class, do what C++ does best, write your own class.  Constantly working directly with windows functions will make your code very, very long and a pain to read.

Another 2 libraries worth knowing as you get into C++ are STL (a must) and Boost (strong should).  Boost especially has a lot of OS abstraction so you don't have to go directly to windows DLLs every time.

Comment: My transition is mainly to MFC, though as in this case I have to use native C++ as well. And yes, you are right; I have been programming in C# for about 3 years now so it is getting used to a lot of inconvenient stuff as you rightly put it.

However diving deep into this, I am beginning to learn and be concerned about a lot of things when writing a program which I never had to worry about with C#. Yes that was easy but this teaches you a lot.

Thanks for the information about the two libraries; I will definitely have a look. Thanks again!

Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad you found my reply useful. C++ has been my home since middle school and professionally for 12 years. Software I write deals a lot with low level network and disk I/O as well as moving around and processing lots of data while paying very close attention to how the memory is utilized.  IMHO C++ will always be a language of choice for these type of applications and with the right set of libraries, even having .NET framework wouldn't provide that much benefit. However...

Comment: ... for UI work, I wouldn't wish it upon anyone to have to write UIs in MFC when you have WPF available to you.  I've done straight Win32, MFC and WTL GUI apps and as far as UIs go, I would pick WPF and C# any day over those technologies.  Plus in terms of skills that employers would look for, I do not see taking the time to learn MFC being much of an investment for your career.  Instead, if you do have code that deserves C++ but want to have a UI for it, write the back end in C++, UI in WPF and use middle layer written in C++/CLI to bridge the gap between the two technologies.

Answer (score 3):

- [Enumerate the subkeys of a key - RegEnumKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Enumerate the values of a key - RegEnumValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You get all subkeys by calling `RegEnumKeyEx` in a loop until it returns `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS`.

In the exact same way, you get all values by calling `RegEnumValue` in a loop until it returns `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS`.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for the MSDN help on RegOpenKeyEx and then go up in the contents you'll find all the related methods: [Registry methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

You probably want to use [RegEnumKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724862%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to enumerate subkeys.